# Position the Title of Custom Joomla Module

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, custom-module

I am trying to move the title of a custom module I built from the default top of the module to an area within the custom code (users have the ability to choose left or right in the options panel and I would like the title to be on the same side as the text.

I am able to get the title with:

```
if ($module->showtitle) {

echo $module-title;
}
```

However I still have the title above the module itself. How can I say "don't show the title in the default position, show it here" ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are using the module chrome feature correctlly, first at all you need a module.php file in a html folder inside your active template, check the beez3 template included in Joomla!

Then in your index.php file when you call the module with a jdoc statement use the module chrome suffix like:

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-8" style="beezDivision" headerLevel="3" />
```

Note that the function has the same name modChrome_beezDivision